Is there a way to get a slice out of a shapely LineString?
I am interested in getting a LineString that is a cutout from an original Shapely LineString. Basically I want the geometry of the red line in the image which is between the two cyan points. I know the location of the points and I know the interpolated distance of the points along the original line (though the interpolation is not quite working right, separate issue). Does Shapely have a way to essentially take a slice out of a line?


Do you have both LineStrings ?

Here is my solution:
from shapely.ops import substring

span_1 = line.line_locate_point(pt1)
span_2 = line.line_locate_point(pt2)
sub_line = substring(line, span_1, span_2)


Just to be clear, is this a complete answer, or additional details for your question?

@joanis it's the answer minus all the needed imports and variable definitions. span_1 and _2 are where along the line the bounding points are and substring returns the slice of the line between those spans

Thanks for the clarification. It would be worth editing the answer to say so in there, and make this Q&A more likely to help future readers with similar questions.
